# Android WebView crashes application

Tags: android, webview, segmentation-fault

I keep getting the error (randomly): `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 5371 (RenderThread)`

It happens mostly when I trigger a card-flip animation to another layout.

I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: that's not your application problem. post the full trace of your application log when the crash occur

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira how do I retrieve this?

Comment: use filter in your logcat then look the cause of your crash ( usually begin with 'caused by...' )

Answer (score 0):

1.try to release the memory:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  mWebView.removeAllViews();
  mWebView.destroy()
}
```

2. try to limit the webview's content